# Can't get my SQL to display my score in my database form my pygame

Tags: python, sql, database, python-2.7

I have tried to create a piece of code so when my game is over or the play wins he score is displayed in the database.

Game Code:

```
 def gameover():
    message = Msg("Game Over")
    message.update()
    player.kill()
    shot.kill()
        SQL = 'INSERT INTO TblScore(Score) VALUES (' + str(score.value)
        Databaseconnector.INSERT(SQL)
```

Database Connection Code:

```
def INSERT(SQL):
    print(SQL)
    cursor.execute(SQL)
    conn.commit()
```

Error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the output of `print(SQL)` as well as the error. (In this case, it would have made the answer obvious.)

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the closing bracket:

```
    SQL = 'INSERT INTO TblScore(Score) VALUES (' + str(score.value) + ')'
                                                                   ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: After including the closing bracket it worked, however it saves the same score 300 times. Any clue of how to fix this.

Comment: nothing in the code you've provided could possibly run 300 times, so... no clue whatsoever.